# sin v/s cos-both give the same answer?

Tags: electromagnetism, wavefunction

Sin or cos-what prompts choosing one over the other ?

1. LR circuits - Say I have a a 'normal' LR circuit with a charged capacitor and an inductor.

(a)The equation for charge can be written as a cosine function. Why did I choose this? The cosine function starts with some positive value(from t=0)and then decreases as the time increases. So, I assume the cosine function because this demonstrates how the function 'starts' from some value - showing that some charge was held initially and then, that charge decreases from there.

(b)Similarly, the current equation is arrived at by differentiating - the 'cos'becomes a 'sin'. This can be explained too. As the charge decreases, the current increases in the circuit and eventually reaches some maximum.

The problem arises like so. When I checked online, it said that 'either' of sin or cos is fine . Also, while problems solving, some of my teachers directly assume a sin function or a cos function. Then they work from there and arrive at the correct answer. Not only that, their initial choice of sin or cos somehow is the right choice and can be found among the options too(MCQ style papers). All this time, my initial wrong choice makes my consequent calculations wrong-for example I chose a cos function, ended up with a sin function which is wrong. At the same time, my teacher chose a sin function and got a cos function which is correct.

2.SHM problems-again the same problem. I choose a sin function as my original equation when I had to choose a cos function.

So, the crux of the problem is this :

1. How to choose the correct 'initial' function for problem solving?

2.Are there some factors which prompts that the cos or sin function would be the better initial choice for the problem?

3.What are the characteristics of the sin or cos function to look out for when looking for the correct initial function?One example would be me choosing the cos function whenever my physical quantity starts from some positive value and decreases as time increases.

Answer (score 2):

As you probably know the sin and cos functions are equivalent, as they are simply shifted by a fixed phase (=angle), $sin(wt) = cos(wt-\pi/2)$. Therefore, we can choose either function.

The key to the solution are the "initial conditions". Often, we know two of the three quantities:

1. initial position of the simple harmonic oscillator, $x(t=0) =x_0$,
2. initial velocity $v(t=0) =v_0$, and
3. initial acceleration, $a(t=0) =a_0$.

By using the function
$$x(t) = A_0 \cdot\sin(wt + \phi_0)$$
we obtain an equation for the amplitude $A_0$, and the initial phase $\phi_0$ by using the "initial conditions". Equivalently, we could have used
$$x(t) = A_0 \cdot\cos(wt + \phi_0)$$
No matter what we use, we end up with the same solution. Just check it out.